# AWK doesn't recognise more than one field when changing value of an element

Tags: shell, csv, awk

I have a csv file, a simplified version of which is:

```
@data
1,2,3,4,normal
1,2,3,4,normal
1,2,3,4,normal
1,2,3,4,normal
1,2,3,4,normal
1,2,3,4,normal
1,2,3,4,normal
1,2,3,4,normal
1,2,3,4,normal
1,2,3,4,normal
```

When I do:

```
awk -F',' '{print NF}' myfile.csv
```

I get:

```
1
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
```

I am trying to change the `5th` element of the `10th` line in this dataset but I noticed a strange behavior upon doing so. More specificaly, when I give:

```
awk -F',' 'NR==10{$5="abnormal"}1' myfile.csv | awk -F',' '{print NF}'
```

I get:

```
1
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
1
5
```

Does anyone has an explanation or any thought on this?

Comment: Can you can give use line `100` so we can see how it looks like? What do you get with this: `awk 'NR==100' myfile.csv`

Comment: 1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,normal

Comment: This line has `200` fields, so not sure whats wrong.

Comment: There is a header on top of my file which is just one field: @data. Obviously this confuses awk. Without paying too much attention the output of my first command was indeed: 1 200 200 200 ... and not 200 200 200. Even though as you can see awk did actually recognized that there are 200 fields on line 100, when I gave the second command awk took the entire line for only one field. Not sure why or even if that's what actually causing this weird behavior but when I tried to remove the header then everything went as expected.

Comment: `There is a header on top of my file which is just one field: @data. Obviously this confuses awk.` - no absolutely not, this in no way will cause awk any kind of problem at all.

Comment: well, yeah - you're removing all of the commas in your fist awk script and then trying to count them in your second one.

Comment: I thought that the -F option would suffice. I had to check its use and now I realize that OFS is necessary. Thanks for the great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @EdMorton for the valuable comment that assigning a value to any field causes the record to be recompiled using the `OFS` value which by default is a `space`.

Updating as per updated question: @drDoom, you are missing `OFS=','.
See the difference in the two outputs below with your sample data:

```
/home/amit/$ awk -F',' 'NR==10{$5="abnormal"}1' OFS=',' myfile.csv | awk -F',' '{print NF}'
1
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
/home/amit/$ awk -F',' 'NR==10{$5="abnormal"}1'  myfile.csv | awk -F',' '{print NF}'
1
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
1
5
```

For changing the 150th field on a 100th line, you can do as below

```
awk -F',' 'NR==100{ $150 = "NewValue"}1' OFS=',' myfile.csv
```

Comment: what I was trying to show with the above code is that when not using the NR==123 check, I get the normal number of fields while when I am using it I get just 1. Obviously using $NF didnt solve the problem

Comment: `NF` should give you the same number, if you have same number of fields on each line. Did you check the 100th line, if you only have 1 field there?

Comment: hm insteresting! there are indeed 200 fields throught the entire file besides the first line which is a header. Probably this gives me hard time. I will test it right now without the header

Comment: if you are specifying `NR==100`, there is no need to test it without header. I am assuming header will also have the same number of fields. As @Jotne asked, can you show us your 100th line?

Comment: Unfortunately, the header has only one field.

Comment: It was my bad ofcourse not see that     awk-F',' '{print NF}' myfile.csv actually gives 1 200 200 200... but then again it's still weird that in that case NF is 200 for line 100 but when    awk-F',' 'NR==100{print NF}' myfile.csv it's only 1.

Comment: Amit, if I run your second command (even without the header on a very normal csv file) the line 100 is printed without commas any idea why?

Comment: Not sure why you are getting this weird behaviour but you can specify a output field separator explicitly. `awk -F',' 'NR==100{ $150 = "NewValue"}1' OFS=',' myfile.csv`

Comment: That's not weird behavior - assign a value to any field causes the record to be recompiled using the OFS value which by default is a space.

Comment: I encourage you to incorporate @EdMorton's comment in your answer, which currently only implicitly contains this information and thus is not easy to glean; to recapitulate: the potentially surprising thing is that assigning to a field causes `$0` to be rebuilt with the value of *`OFS`* rather than `FS`.

Comment: I appreciate the update, Amit. Can I also suggest that you remove the original bits of your answer (starting with `You should use`)? Given the revised question, they no longer add value to the answer and may even be a distraction.

Comment: `surprising thing is that assigning to a field causes $0 to be rebuilt with the value of OFS` that's exactly as documented and makes sense when you consider that the reason to change a field is to OUTPUT the modified record.

Answer (score 0):

Any or all of these are the issue:

a) Your csv file was created on Windows and so has extraneous control-M characters in it.

b) Your separator is not a comma [on every line].

c) You are miscounting which line is the 100th one.

Do this and update your question with the output:

```
dos2unix file
awk -F',' -v OFS=':' 'NR>98 && NR<102{print NR, NF, $1, $0}' file
```

Note that I said update your *question* with the output - do NOT post the output as a *comment*, as we will not be able to see the format.

Comment: Thats a valid point, but I thought since `^M` are at the end, `awk` should still have split the line on `-F,`. I could be wrong too.

Comment: Once control-Ms are in the picture all bets are off. I added a couple of other things that could be the issue too.

Comment: First of all thanks for the help! as far as Ed's sugestions a) no it wasn't written in windows and there are no c-Ms for sure, b) there is a comma on every line except the first one which is a dummy header of one element/field (can be removed easily but after more extensive testing i realised it didnt make any difference really), c) no, for sure. I have edited the entire question with a more easy-to-read dataset.

Comment: What you posted is unrelated to your original question. What you have now is replacing all commas with spaces and then trying to count commas.